# Find IPv6 Router advertising a prefix

Tags: ipv6

I am using a Centos 5.5 box. Something on the network is advertising IPv6 prefixes, and I want to know who.

One solution would be to install tcpdump or tshark and just look at the network traffic. I would prefer not to have to rewire the network or play rpm sherpa with scp.

Is there a utility, like `route` or `ip` that will show me the addresses of the routers sending the advertisements?

Comment: out of curiosity why does it matter?

Comment: @JimB - because an IPv6 RA is basically like having a rogue DHCP server on the network. Very bad.

Comment: Why are you avoiding tcpdump or TShark? If you don't know what's on your network then you don't really own it.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way I know to do this is to just accept the route it's advertising.  Once it's your inet6 router, it's easy.

```
$ ip -f inet6 route
2001:db8:dead:beef::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 3523sec mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0
fe80::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0
default via fe80::21b:63ff:fe12:3456 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 1024  expires 1722sec mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 64
```

'default via' is my router here.  Let's see who it actually is, by querying my ARP neighbors.

```
$ ip -f inet6 neigh
fe80::21b:63ff:fe12:3456 dev eth1 lladdr 00:1b:63:12:34:56 router STALE

$ ip -f inet neigh
10.0.0.1 dev eth1 lladdr 00:1b:63:12:34:56 STALE
```

So I've found an inet6 router with a MAC address 00:1b:63:12:34:56, and a v4 address 10.0.0.1.  Hopefully that'd be enough clues to send you back into familiar territory.

Answer (score 3):

radvdump (installed alongside radvd) will provide you what you want as well...

Answer (score 2):

The `rdisc6` utility, included in most Linux distributions, does what you want.